# How to get job id using spring expression language?

Tags: spring-batch

I want to get job id using spring expression language. I tried `#{jobExecutionContext[jobId]}` but it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using SpEL alone, there is no way to access the job id.  You could use a JobExecutionListener to add it to the executionContext and then it would be available via what you are trying.

Comment: @MichaelMinella This answer is rather old, I think it's worth updating. Both `#{jobExecution.jobInstance.instanceId}` and `#{jobExecution.jobId}` provided the value of instance id for me.

Answer (score 4):

Use scope="step" and then an expression in your query (or its parameters): #{stepExecution.jobExecution.id} (the root of the expression is a StepContext).

Comment: This should be the the actual accepted answer. This is documented on spring batch documentation and its working too.

Answer (score 3):

A worked example would look like this. Your JobExecutionListener class has access to the JobExecution and it copies the jobId to the executionContext.

```
public class JobIdToContextExecutionListener implements JobExecutionListener {

    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        long jobId = jobExecution.getJobId();
        jobExecution.getExecutionContext().put("jobId",jobId);
    }

    ..
}
```

In your spring context, you can then reference the jobId via SpEL like

```
#{stepExecution.jobExecution.jobId}
```

or

```
#{jobExecutionContext.jobId}
```

See [Luca's answer on referencing late-binding parameters here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549951/spring-batch-flatfileitemwriter-how-to-use-stepexecution-jobid-to-generate-fil?lq=1).

Answer (score 1):

`#{stepExecution.jobExecution.id}` or `#{stepExecution.jobExecutionId}` should work though.

The [StepContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/scope/context/StepContext.html) **does** provide access to the StepExecution for late binding via SpEL expressions.