# Spring Batch FlatFileItemWriter - How to use stepExecution.jobId to generate file name

Tags: spring-batch

I have this `FileWriter` where I'm trying to append the current Job Id to the filename that is generated.

```
<bean id="csvFileWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="resource">
        <bean class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource">
            <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String">
                <value>${csv.file}_#{stepExecution.jobExecution.jobId}</value>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="lineAggregator">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
            <property name="delimiter">
                <util:constant
                    static-field="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer.DELIMITER_COMMA"/>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldExtractor">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.PassThroughFieldExtractor" />
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    ....
....
```

but it's bombing out with

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'stepExecution' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:208)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:72)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:52)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:97)
    at org.springframework.expression.common.CompositeStringExpression.getValue(CompositeStringExpression.java:82)
    at org.springframework.expression.common.CompositeStringExpression.getValue(CompositeStringExpression.java:1)
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:139)
    ... 45 more
```

Any idea how i can correctly reference the `jobId` in this case?

**Update: Adding worked solution**

I implemented the `JobExecutionListener` which adds the `jobId` to the `ExecutionContext`

```
public class MyExecutionListener implements JobExecutionListener {

    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        long jobId = jobExecution.getJobId();
        jobExecution.getExecutionContext().put("jobId",jobId);
        jobExecution.getExecutionContext().put("date",date);
    }

    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
```

Register the listener to the batch job

```
<batch:job id="batchJob">
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="myExecutionListener"/>
    </batch:listeners>
```

And finally the CSV writer gets updated to

```
<bean id="fundAssetCsvFileWriter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter" scope="step">
    <property name="resource">
        <bean class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource">
            <constructor-arg value="${csv.file.name}_#{jobExecutionContext['date']}_#{jobExecutionContext['jobId']}.csv" type="java.lang.String"/>
        </bean>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The supported names for late-bindig are:

- `#{jobParameters}`
- `#{jobExecutionContext}`
- `#{stepExecutionContext}`

If `jobId` is not directly accessible, look [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149302/how-to-get-job-id-using-spring-expression-language).

Also, `resource` can be injected directly as

```
<property name="resource">
  <value>file://${csv.file}_#{jobExecutionContext['jobId']}</value>
</property>
```

because the right resource type is created using a converter.

Answer (score 1):

`#{stepExecution.jobExecution.id}` or `#{stepExecution.jobExecutionId}` should work though.

The [StepContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/scope/context/StepContext.html) **does** provide access to the StepExecution for late binding via SpEL expressions.