# How can I get jobId in ItemWriter in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Is it possible to get jobId or JobName in ItemWriter in spring batch.

I read about [late binding](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html-single/index.html#late-binding) but not sure how to use it to get job name or job id in Item Writer.

I configured my writer as

```
    <bean id="myWriter" ref="com.eg.man.EodWriter" scope="step">
     <property name="jobInstanceId" value="#{stepExecution.jobExecution.jobId}"/>
    </bean>
```

but I don't know how to use it in writer class to get value.

**Edit** I also found [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/77344-job-instance-id-in-writer) link which say you can get id in Write but again how to use it in writer class

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring Batch FlatFileItemWriter - How to use stepExecution.jobId to generate file name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549951/spring-batch-flatfileitemwriter-how-to-use-stepexecution-jobid-to-generate-fil)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know about your method doing it with xml, but here is how I would do it:

You need to add a field and a method to your class (be it writer or reader) such as

```
private Long jobId;

@BeforeStep
public void getInterstepData(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    JobExecution jobExecution = stepExecution.getJobExecution();
    this.jobId = jobExecution.getJobId();
}
```

In this case the method will be called before the step and the id will be accessible through the field.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That worked but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549951/spring-batch-flatfileitemwriter-how-to-use-stepexecution-jobid-to-generate-fil, seems more proper way of getting this done

Comment: It is possible to get the jobId directly from `StepExecution` by: `stepExecution.getJobExecutionId();`