# Add parameter to job context from tasklet step and use in later steps in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring-batch

For now, I'm using jobParameters to get the filenames for both my FlatFileItemReader and FlatFileItemWriter. It's okay for testing my batch, but my goal is to read a file in some directory (there is only this file in this directory) and the filename might change. The output filename should depend on the input filename.

Therefore, I thought about adding a new step to my job, and this step will set both output and input filenames by searching the good directory and looking for the file into it. I read [Passing Data to Future Steps](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/patterns.html) from Spring Doc, and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549951/spring-batch-flatfileitemwriter-how-to-use-stepexecution-jobid-to-generate-fil) from SO, but I can't make it work, the files are always "null".

First, I've defined the following Tasklet

```
public class SettingFilenamesTasklet implements Tasklet {

    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        // TODO Search folder and set real filenames
        String inputFilename = "D:/TestInputFolder/dataFile.csv";
        String outputFilename = "D:/TestOutputFolder/dataFile-processed.csv";
        ExecutionContext stepContext = stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
        stepContext.put("inputFile", inputFilename);
        stepContext.put("outputFile", outputFilename);
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }

    @BeforeStep
    public void saveStepExecution(StepExecution stepExec) {
        stepExecution = stepExec;
    }
}
```

Then, I added the promotionListener bean

```
@Bean
public ExecutionContextPromotionListener promotionListener() {
    ExecutionContextPromotionListener listener = new ExecutionContextPromotionListener();
    listener.setKeys(new String[]{
            "inputFile", "outputFile"
    });
    return listener;
}
```

I changed the jobParameters by a jobExecutionContext in my FlatFileItemWriter definition (I didn't change a single line to the code itself)

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemWriter<RedevableCRE> flatFileWriter(@Value("#{jobExecutionContext[outputFile]}") String outputFile) {
    FlatFileItemWriter<Employee> flatWriter = new FlatFileItemWriter<Employee>();
    FileSystemResource isr;
    isr = new FileSystemResource(new File(outputFile));
    flatWriter.setResource(isr);
    DelimitedLineAggregator<RedevableCRE> aggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<RedevableCRE>();
    aggregator.setDelimiter(";");
    BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<RedevableCRE> beanWrapper = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<RedevableCRE>();
    beanWrapper.setNames(new String[]{
        "id", "firstName", "lastName", "phone", "address"
    });
    aggregator.setFieldExtractor(beanWrapper);
    flatWriter.setLineAggregator(aggregator);
    flatWriter.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
    return flatWriter;
}
```

I added my Tasklet bean

```
@Bean
public SettingFilenamesTasklet settingFilenames() {
    return new SettingFilenamesTasklet();
}
```

And I created a new Step to add in my job declaration

```
@Bean
public Step stepSettings(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, SettingFilenamesTasklet tasklet, ExecutionContextPromotionListener listener) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepSettings").tasklet(tasklet).listener(listener).build();
}
```

For now, the FlatFileItemReader still uses the jobParameters value, I want to make my FlatFileItemWriter work first. I get the following error :

```
[...]    
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter]: Factory method 'flatFileWriter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:591)
    ... 87 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at batchTest.BatchConfiguration.flatFileWriter(BatchConfiguration.java:165)
    at batchTest.BatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5d415889.CGLIB$flatFileWriter$1(<generated>)
    at batchTest.BatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5d415889$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$969a8527.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
    at batchTest.BatchConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5d415889.flatFileWriter(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 88 common frames omitted
```

I tried to replace the @StepScope annotation by @JobScope ; to put my parameters directly into jobExecutionContext (+ JobExecutionListener) instead of using StepContext + promotionListener... Nothing works. The resource file is always null when I try to create the FlatFileItemWriter.

What am I missing ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you try to add `@BeforeStep` to your writer and place a breakpoint to check what is in `stepExecution.getExecutionContext()` and `stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext()`? Remove `@Value` so you can start your job for now.

Comment: It looks like my code doesn't even execute the `@BeforeStep` method I wrote... I created a class extending FlatFileItemWriter in order to test what you said (I don't see how to add a `@BeforeStep` in the batch configuration otherwise), that I instantiate instead of the generic FlatFileItemWriter in my code. My debugger doesn't stop on the breakpoints I've set...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In tasklet you have `ChunkContext` at your disposal so you do not need `@BeforeStep`, you can remove it (in my configuration it is not invoked at all, and when you think of it as one action step does not make much sense but I do not see NPE so guess that part work). We solved it with one of two approaches:

1. You can put any parameter from tasklet to job `ExecutionContext` directly using `chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("inputFile", inputFilename);`
2. You can add `ExecutionContextPromotionListener` to your tasklet step and then do `chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getExecutionContext().put("inputFile", inputFilename);`

Comment: I tried both solutions, I still have the same error message. Should I do anything more, or it's supposed to work with my actual configuration ?

Comment: My mistake : I wasn't using the good listener for the 2nd solution. It works well, thank you !